# Magento Extension Error base table not found

Tags: mysql, magento

I have just installed a Extension on Magento. When i try to reach the extension in the backend. I am getting the following error.

`There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.ma2_slideshow' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ma2_slideshow` AS `main_table``

Do i need to add tables to my database? Because normally the extension adds an table to the database right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension should create the tables with an installer script.

However, if might have failed for some reason and the installer might have not run. By the table name it seems that you are trying to install Ma2 Slideshow, try manually creating the table by running the following sql statement (Taken from the installer script):

```
CREATE TABLE `ma2_slideshow` (
  `slideshow_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `slideshow_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `sortorder` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `content` text NOT NULL default '',
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `created_time` datetime NULL,
  `update_time` datetime NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`slideshow_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Alternatively**, you can search on the table `core_resource` for some entry like `slideshow_setup`. Delete that entry and clear cache, that should -hopefully- trigger the install script again.

I hope that helps.